# C# Xamarin.Android images are displayed in the file manager and not in the gallery

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, gallery

I made an application to save photos on the phone.

```
public void DownloadImage(string linkbitmap, string title)
    {           
        Bitmap bitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(linkbitmap).Result;
        var path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures + "/Tsundere");
        var complete = path.AbsolutePath;           
        var filepatch = System.IO.Path.Combine(complete, title + ".jpg");
        var filestream = new FileStream(filepatch, FileMode.Create);
        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, filestream);
        filestream.Close();
    }
```

The pictures are displayed in the file manager, but in the example the discord application does not have them. I have to restart the phone to be visible. How to make photos immediately visible in other applications, such as photos from the camera or photos downloaded from facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem. Just add `MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Android.App.Application.Context, new string[] {path}, null, null);`in the code
description this class https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Media.MediaScannerConnection/

Answer (score 0):

Construct an Intent action (`Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile`) with a uri that includes the file path:

```
using (var file = new Java.IO.File(path))
using (var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file))
{
    var scanFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile, uri);
    SendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
}
```

FYI: You can create/register a BroadcastReceiver that listens for  `Intent.ActionMediaScannerFinished` to determine when the media scanner is done processing your request.